# how to type the html tag as text in span using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

From Api , getting the value "Evidence" like "`<FORM METHOD="get" ACTION="search">`"

```
{
    data: {
        evidence:<FORM METHOD="get" ACTION="search">
    }
}
```

ts file :

```
public evidence : any;
    
getEvidence(){
    this.service.getevidence().subscribe(data => {
        this.evidence= data.data.evidence                  // here we have the value
    });
```

html file :

```
<span [innerHTML]="evidence"></span>
```

I want to display the value but getting the issue like

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content

Comment: Check DomSanitizer please

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass sanitizing in the component itself,

**app.component.ts :**

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

public evidence : any;

constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {}

bypass(v:string):SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
}

getEvidence(){
    this.service.getevidence().subscribe(data => {
        this.evidence= bypass(data.data.evidence);
    });
}
```

Or you can write a pipe so that it's reusable,

**sanitizeHtml.pipe.ts :**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(v:string):SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html :**

```
<span [innerHTML]="evidence | sanitizeHtml"></span>
```